# how would i write a recursive function to add all numbers in a deeply nested list of numbers and words

Tags: python

Hello i am having trouble doing this problem it asks me to Write a recursive function that adds all the numbers in a deeply nested list which is made up  numbers and words.

I have tried it but have gotten no where.

Comment: you havent even posted an example of the `list`...

Comment: [1,"b",[4.7, 'a', -1, 99, ['hi', [7, 0]]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Flatten (an irregular) list of lists in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2158395/2823755)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
def nested_sum(q):
    sum = 0
    for v in q:
        if type(v) == int or type(v) == float:
            sum += v
        elif type(v) == list:
            sum += nested_sum(v)
    return sum
```

Answer (score 3):

I would start with a "filter" function yielding just the numbers: using Py 3.4 or better, that might be

```
import numbers
def getnumbers(alist, number_class=numbers.Number):
    for x in alist:
        if isinstance(x, number_class):
            yield x
        elif isinstance(x, list):
            yield from getnumbers(x)
```

(easy to translate to older versions if needed, just less elegant:-).

Then,

```
sum(getnumbers(alist))
```

will do the job.

I think this "factoring out" the pick of all numbers and nothing but numbers from a deeply nested list of numbers and words, vs summing them, makes for much more elegant and reusable code than trying to squash both tasks into a single function.

Comment: what is the yield used for ?

Comment: @jesuscaballero, `yield` produces an item then continues from the same place as the caller asks for another (by looping), while `return` would finish off the function's execution.  `sum` implicitly loops, so gets all items.  Functions using `yield` are known as **generators**.

Answer (score 1):

```
total = 0

def flat_sum(q):
    global total
    if not q:
        return
    if isinstance(q, list):
        if not isinstance(q[0], list) and not isinstance(q[0], str):
            total += q[0]
        else:
            flat_sum(q[0])
        flat_sum(q[1:])
    else:
        if not isinstance(q, str):
            total += q

flat_sum([1,"b",[4.7, 'a', -1, 99, ['hi', [7, 0]]]])
print total
```

Comment: would this work for a list with both words and numbers

Comment: Adding numbers with words? That does not make a lot of sense. What is your use case?

Comment: The list contains both words and numbers but all you have to do is add the numbers together not the words.

Comment: Yes, it will work now. I've fixed it to do that.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `numbers.Number` to check for any number type.

```
from numbers import Number

def flat_sum(lst):
    if len(lst) == 0:
        return 0

    hd, tl = lst[0], lst[1:]

    if isinstance(hd, list):
        return flat_sum(hd) + flat_sum(tl)
    elif isinstance(hd, Number):
        return hd + flat_sum(tl)
    else:
        return flat_sum(tl)
```